# What was the SquashFS compression method?

Tags: linux, terminal, compression, squashfs

I've got some SquashFS files, and I'd like to know how they were compressed so that I can have a rough idea of how they would perform when mounted.

The only binaries  provided by the `squashfs-tools` package are `mksquashfs` and `unsquashfs`, which are for creating/appending SquashFS files and extracting SquashFS files, respectively.

How can I determine what compression method was used to make a specific SquashFS file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsquashfs -s` did not have the capability of displaying the compression type used until [this commit on 07 August 2009](https://sourceforge.net/p/squashfs/code/ci/836a2c).  This means that if you are running `squashfs-tools` 4.0 or older, you wouldn't be able to see the compression method used.

From this information, I derived a way to read the SquashFS 4.0 superblock to determine the compression method used (where `$SQUASHFS` is the path to your SquashFS file):

```
dd if=$SQUASHFS bs=1 count=2 skip=20 2>/dev/zero | od -An -tdI | xargs
```

Alternatively, here's a function for those who would like to type in the filename at the end of the line:

```
sqsh_comp_method(){ dd if="$1" bs=1 count=2 skip=20 2>/dev/zero|od -An -tdI | xargs;};sqsh_comp_method
```

You will get a number (between 1 and 6 as of SquashFS 4.4).  You can match that number to the following table to see what compression method was used:

```
╔═══╦════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ # ║ Compression Method ║ Compatible Version ║
╠═══╬════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ gzip               ║ 1.0 and newer      ║
║ 2 ║ lzma               ║ 4.1 and newer      ║
║ 3 ║ lzo                ║ 4.1 and newer      ║
║ 4 ║ xz                 ║ 4.2 and newer      ║
║ 5 ║ lz4                ║ 4.3 and newer      ║
║ 6 ║ zstd               ║ 4.4 and newer      ║
╚═══╩════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

<sup><sub>([Source](https://sourceforge.net/p/squashfs/code/ci/e38956b92f738518c29734399629e7cdb33072d3/tree/squashfs-tools/squashfs_fs.h#l275))</sub></sup>

Note that the above `dd` command will only provide a reliable output if the file you specified had a SquashFS 4.0 superblock.  The following command will output "`Not SquashFS 4.0`" if the file `$SQUASHFS` does not have the SquashFS 4.0 magic number:

```
if [[ "$(dd if="$SQUASHFS" bs=1 count=4 skip=28 2>/dev/zero | xxd -p)" != "04000000" ]] ; then echo -n "Not " ; fi ; echo "SquashFS 4.0"
```

### Explanation

In SquashFS 4.0 filesystems, the compression method is stored on the 21<sup>st</sup> and 22<sup>nd</sup> bytes of the superblock as a data type `short`.  `dd bs=1 count=2 skip=20` will retrieve the `short`, `od -An -tdI` will turn the `short` into a human-readable number, and `xargs` is just to get rid of the leading spaces.

Before SquashFS 4.0, there was only the **gzip** method.

---

#### Old answer

`unsquashfs` has the `-s` flag for displaying SquashFS filesystem information.

Example usage:

```
deltik@node51 [/tmp]# unsquashfs -s template.squashfs
Found a valid SQUASHFS 4:0 superblock on template.squashfs.
Creation or last append time Thu Apr 30 23:07:23 2015
Filesystem size 47225242.44 Kbytes (46118.40 Mbytes)
Compression gzip
Block size 131072
Filesystem is exportable via NFS
Inodes are compressed
Data is compressed
Fragments are compressed
Always_use_fragments option is not specified
Xattrs are compressed
Duplicates are removed
Number of fragments 23629
Number of inodes 437076
Number of ids 1
```

If you just want the compression type identified, you could pipe the output through `awk '/^Compression/{print $2}'`.  Example:

```
deltik@node51 [/tmp]# unsquashfs -s template.squashfs | awk '/^Compression/{print $2}'
gzip
```

Answer (score 2):

The `file` utility at version 5.39 and above support displaying the squashfs compression. If giving `file` a block device, one needs to tell it not to care that it's a special file and look inside as if it was a file.

```
file --special-files /dev/mmcblk0p1
/dev/mmcblk0p1: Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, zlib compressed, 817826784 bytes, 27633 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: Mon Nov 29 20:51:12 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Also looking for a better answer. I'm assuming you want to know because your OS doesn't seem to support the compression used in providing you with the squashedfs in question. Or perhaps like the unsquashfs on CentOS6, yours doesn't report the Compression type.

So I  `strings | head` on the compressed file. The first line will be `hsqs` and the second line *should*  indicate the compression method used.  I believe I used this method to determine that `7zXZ` indicating that 7zip was in fact the method. However, with `gzip`, no such luck. I have to use `od -b` on the file to get the octal dump and to try to match the file signature with those associated with the `file` program. Again, however, no such luck (the string I expected to find is `037 213` but I see only `037 221`.

Comment: You had a good idea to look at the superblock for compression information.  I've updated [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/919026/83694) with a superblock analysis.

Comment: @Deltik You are very cool.